# Raster (.tif) files fail to load after ~15 minutes on ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap

When using ArcMap 10.6, the base mapping we use fails to draw after about 15 mins and also any other rasters (these are all .Tif files) fail to draw as well. It shows a black box or is just white, as shown in picture below.

I have to keep restarting the Mxd and this becomes quite a pain. Can anyone shed any light on what may be causing this?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your MXD is corrupted.  What happens if you load one of your rasters into a completely fresh project?

Comment: @MappaGnosis Hi, I've tried a new mxd and the same thing happens also! It might be worth noting that our server is encrypted and this could potentially have something to do with it. I'll try copying the rasters on to the laptop hard drive and then see if the problem happens.